# ffmpeg using multiple filters

Tags: filter, ffmpeg

I'm kinda new to ffmpeg, but I found it quite useful to turn image sequences into sprite sheet, but I need to skip frames. I've tried this but it skip the 1st filter. How could I make both -vf work?

```
ffmpeg -start_number 0150 -i %04d.png -vf framestep=10 -vf "tile=12x30" -an -vsync 0 spritesheet.png
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the same option two times then only its last occurence counts. You need to use one `-filter_complex` instead of two `-vf` filters, for example:

`-filter_complex "[0:v]framestep=10[a];[a]tile=12x30[out]" -map [out]:v`

Comment: Omg. It work perfectly fine. Thanks you very much. It saved me a lot of work.

Comment: @Alexandre Welcome to StackOverflow. If an answer, answers your question to your satisfaction, remember to `Accept` it and possibly upvote it as well. To accept an answer, click the Grey Tick beside it. To upvote, click the up-arrow. It's important, as it makes the answer easier for others, with a similar question, to find.